# Magento cron job is not running on AWS instance

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services, cron

I'm running Magento in AWS, Amazon linux. Suddenly cron job stops running. I have following cron command in crontab,

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/MAGENTO/test.php
* * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/html/MAGENTO/cron.sh
```

can anybody shed me light on it,

Comment: How do you know that it is not running?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Hem Did you found solution, if so please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the output/error to a log file and see what's the issue.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/MAGENTO/test.php > /var/log/magento-exe.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Install this extension & check whether cron is running or not.

https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler

credits : @Yorrd

You don't need to execute many commands, the most important thing is that you edit your crontab file. I don't know how this works on Amazon's servers, usually you can do it via crontab -e though (e for edit).

In that file you need to add a new rule which calls the cron.php every so often. The format of this is (borrowed from your link):

```
* * * * *  /bin/sh /absolute/path/to/magento/cron.sh
```

Format of this: The first 5 stars stand for minutes, hours, days, weeks and months. Then the shell which you want to run your script (just use /bin/sh) and finally the path to your cron.sh which you need to look up yourself (in your Magento root usually).

We're doing this every minute, because cron.php will take care which scripts to run when and just needs a heartbeat.

or you may contact your hosting providers.

If you successfully add this line as I described above and Amazon didn't disable cron jobs or something, this should work.